# Facebook style content container

Tags: css, border

On facebook, the container that the content is in (when your logged in) has a 1px gray border on each side and on the bottom.  However, the bottom border always stays the same distance from the bottom of the page even if the content area expands (possibly due to javascript).

I probably didn't explain that clearly, but all I am looking for is to create a content area with left, right and bottom borders.  When the content area expands id like the bottom border to be pushed down, but still be connected to the side borders like one big rectangle and id like the bottom border to remain the same distance from the bottom of the page.  NOT the same distance from the bottom of the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<div id="container">
 <h1>hello</h1>
 <p>Lorem ipsum etc.</p>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
#container {
 border: 1px solid grey;
 }
</style>
```

That will show the grey border all the way around the content and will expand as necessary; or did you mean something else?

Comment: but how will it maintain the same distance from the bottom.  say, for example 20px